# Manjaro/Arch: keep installed packages across multiple machines synchonized

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, manjaro, pacman

I am running multiple Manjaro installation on a two laptops and two desktops and I often find myself in the situation that I need the same software on all machines and have to manually install it on all of them.
Is there a way to sync the the installations of packages across my machines? Bandwith saving and [setting up a package cache](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Tips_and_tricks#Network_shared_pacman_cache) is not my interest.
I looked at [Topgrade](https://github.com/r-darwish/topgrade) which offers to update multiple machines but this is just keeping packages up to date and it is not syncing installed software as far as I can see.

Comment: you can use ansible for that. and stop installing packages manually.

Comment: I had a look at Ansible and it is certainly very interesting software - only issue I see - I will have to use the playbooks from my Ansible instance instead using pacman on my machines. So when on the go and I install a software with pacman on my laptop I still have to remember to add it to the playbook for all machines.

Comment: yes... and no... you can create a ansible playbook that executes a script that lists all the installed packages on the computers, removes duplicates and then execute a playbook that send the command to install those packages on all the machines. If you'd like I can post an example of the script that I use for my RHEL servers.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could share the script . Thank you.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer below

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a request from the OP (refer to comments on the OP question for details) for a script that collects installed packages.

Please keep in mind that the below script is for RHEL (Red Hat Entrerprise Linux), if you are running a different system you can still use it by update the specific package manager commands to match your system.

```
#!/bin/bash
# VARS
# declare the hostnames of your servers. it requires to have a config file inside ./ssh with the connection information.
HOSTS=" prd_webserver1 prd_webserver2 prd_db1 prd_db2 prd_frontend1 prd_frontend2"
# create a store directory on the path were the script is
store="artifact_store"
# declare roles based on hostname
role_store="webserver db frontend"

# Create artifact_store directory
[ ! -d "$store" ] && mkdir -p "$store"

# Create role store directories
for ROLE_DIR in ${role_store}; do
[ ! -d "$store/${ROLE_DIR}" ] && mkdir -p "$store/${ROLE_DIR}"
done

CMDS=$(cat <<CMD
 bash -c "sudo yum -q check-update --security --exclude=kernel* |awk '{print $ 1}' > /tmp/updatelist.log"
CMD
)

# Create update lists
for HOSTNAME in ${HOSTS}; do
ssh -t ${HOSTNAME} "$CMDS"
scp ${HOSTNAME}:/tmp/updatelist.log ./updatelist_${HOSTNAME}.log
mv updatelist_${HOSTNAME}.log $store
done

# Create role directories and move artifacts
for ROLE in ${role_store}; do
mv $store/*${ROLE}*.log $store/${ROLE}
cat $store/${ROLE}/updatelist_*.log >> $store/${ROLE}/updatelist.combined
cat $store/${ROLE}/updatelist.combined |sort |uniq >> $store/${ROLE}/updatelist.final
rm $store/${ROLE}/updatelist.combined
done
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Could you tell me why the CMDS variable is declared this way? Wouldn't simply writing  CMDS=$(bash -c "sudo yum -q ....) be the same?

Comment: well, i've tried several methods to send the command and came to this solution because 1 - the sudo requires a password and using a here doc would not ask for it. 2 - because of the pipe to the awk that was trying to evaluated the $1. This was they i came up to make it work. It might not be the most elegant or correct but it work. If someone here as a better solution please share it.